# sqlite subquery syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite, syntax-error

I have a syntax error in this subquery that I cannot seem to figure out why it won't work. All the parens are matched

```
select min(max_s) 
from 
(select max(salary) from instructor group by dept_name) 
as s(max_s);

Error: near "(": syntax error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT MIN(x.max_s) 
  FROM (SELECT MAX(i.salary) AS max_s 
          FROM INSTRUCTOR i
      GROUP BY i.dept_name) x
```

Comment: I don't understand why the second half of your answer would be true. I'm trying to find the minimum after grouping by department and then finding the maximums of that group.

Comment: @controlfreak123: Sorry, I misread.  I usually include the column I'm grouping by in the output to see what the value is attached to, so I didn't read closely & assumed the inner query was going to return only one row/record.

Comment: thats quite alright. I also noticed that I can leave off the x alias because it knows that max_s is in the subquery.

Comment: @controlfreak123: Some databases (mySQL, SQL Server) require a table alias for a derived table/inline view; I always define table aliases.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the `AS s(max_s)` table alias, which doesn't look quite right.  You should alias the column name inside the subquery, for example:

```
select min(s.max_s) 
from 
(select max(salary) as max_s from instructor group by dept_name) 
as s
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put parens after a table alias.